# fail to display block element correctly in terminal

Tags: terminal, conemu

When I use `plotext` to plot graph in Linux terminial which is connected via ssh, I find that it fails to display block elements correctly.

Here is the command I use

```bash
python3 -c "import plotext as plt; y = plt.sin(); plt.scatter(y); plt.title('Scatter Plot'); plt.show()"
```

And the output is
[image]

Some of the block elements, for examples ▝,▖ are displayed as question mark.

Is there anything I can do to make it right? My terminal setting is `TERM=xterm-256color`

#### Update

Turn out to be the problem of ConEmu

Comment: Choose another temrinal emulator.

Comment: Which one would work?

Answer (score 1):

Turn out to be a problem of ConEmu, it can be fixed by the method provided here: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1381

- Install DejaVu font family: https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/
- In ConEmu's Setting -> Font page, set both font and alternative font to `DejaVu Sans Mono`

Comment: Just to clarify. It's a problem of the Font you tried to use in ConEmu. The ConEmu cannot magically render glyphs which are absent in the Font you've selected.